# Video compression software for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, media-streaming

We have 65 employees that record videos of 1-1.5 hours length. These videos are quite large. Is there any "good" compression software than can be used to minimize file size before the videos get uploaded to their SharePoint Online site?

Comment: I think it is not SharePoint related question

Comment: Whoever is voting to close GG. I am asking about the SharePoint platform and it is on topic as this sentence proves: "We accept questions about the SharePoint platform. This is defined as the functionality within"

Comment: You are asking about  any "good" compression software, not SharePoint. I will not vote down, it is just my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such build in function in SP Online (that I know of as everything changes on the monthly basis)

MS provides some compression mechanism if you embed the video in the presentation. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compress-your-media-files-a45c956a-f4a6-4d47-99ef-b408ac5a9a6b

You would have to create workflow that would call an automated service (Azure Function for example) that would compress the video and replace the original file.

Or have a 3rd party software to compress it manually by users before uploading.